# How to use Pa_IsStreamActive in PortAudio?

Tags: portaudio

I use PortAudio V19-devel (pa_stable_v19_20140130) to synthesize the output of a text-to-speech engine.

First, I've registered a function using `PaStreamFinishedCallback (void *userData)`, so that it gets called when the audio stream becomes inactive.

According to the [Stream State Machine](http://portaudio.com/docs/proposals/010-ClarifyStreamStateMachine.html), while beeing in state "Active" (in other words beeing in the callback for processing audio data) and returning `paAbort`, we trigger a transition to state "Callback finished" and `Pa_IsStreamActive` returns 0, after all buffers have been canceled.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this right, since `Pa_IsStreamActive` returns 1 after an `paAbort`. The question is how to determine that all buffers have been canceled? Below you can find the corresponding snippets of my code:

```
int AudioConnection::onAudioDataReceived (const void *input, void *output,
        unsigned long frames, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *time,
        PaStreamCallbackFlags status, void *userdata
    ) {

    int finished;
    unsigned int i;
    AudioConnection *data = (AudioConnection *)userdata;
    unsigned int framesLeft = data->numFrames - data->cursor;

    int8_t *out = (int8_t *)output;

    // Declared to prevent unused variable warnings
    (void) time; (void) input; (void) status;

    if (framesLeft >= frames) {
        for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
            *out++ = data->audioSamples[data->cursor++];
            *out++ = data->audioSamples[data->cursor++];

        }
        data->cursor += frames;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    else if (framesLeft == 0) {
        *out++ = 0;
        *out++ = 0;
        data->cursor = 0;
        finished = paAbort;
    }

    // final buffer
    else if (framesLeft < frames) {
        for (i = 0; i < framesLeft; i++) {
            *out++ = data->audioSamples[data->cursor++];
            *out++ = data->audioSamples[data->cursor++];
        }
        data->cursor = 0;
        finished = paComplete;
    }

    // should never happen
    else {
        finished = paAbort;
    }

    return finished;
}
```

This is my callback code, that gets called after audio stream has finished:

```
void AudioConnection::onAudioStreamFinished (void *userdata) {

    AudioConnection *data = (AudioConnection *) userdata;

    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_TRACE, ACE_TEXT ("(%t | %P | %D | %N) AudioConnection::onAudioStreamFinished ()\n")));
    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_TRACE, ACE_TEXT ("(%t | %P | %D | %N) AudioConnection::isAudioStreamActive () = %d \n"), data->isAudioStreamActive ()));
}
```

And

```
bool AudioConnection::isAudioStreamActive () {

    return Pa_IsStreamActive (audioStream) ? true : false;
}
```

The following trace indicates the problem- I would expect that `isAudioStreamActive` in the last line returns 0. Any feedback on this is appreciated. Thanks!

```
(1987417168 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:30.935040 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection::isAudioStreamActive () = 0 
(1987417168 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:30.936162 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection::playAudioStream ()
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:30.977247 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 27648 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.007114 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 26112 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.037122 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 24576 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.067106 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 23040 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.097107 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 21504 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.137147 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 19968 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.187113 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 18432 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.237124 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 16896 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.287146 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 15360 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.337112 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 13824 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.387106 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 12288 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.437225 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 10752 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.487161 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 9216 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.537158 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 7680 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.587206 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 6144 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.637156 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 4608 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.687188 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 3072 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.737236 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 1536 
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.787165 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection framesLeft: 0 .......silence.
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.787428 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection::onAudioStreamFinished ()
(1954542672 | 19339 | 2016-09-27 23:10:31.787736 | ../src/AudioConnection.cpp) AudioConnection::isAudioStreamActive () = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `Pa_IsStreamActive` depends on which host you use. It's not so surprising that it returns 1 after `paAbort` since that means something anomalous occurred and PortAudio should quit immediately. Most likely in this case you want to use `paComplete` instead. I think you want `framesLeft <= frames` for "final buffer".